# i want to get the array values before viewDidLoad in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

i want to get all the images from the particular album while the app launched, so I used to get the images by the `enumerateGroupsWithTypes`.
i put the code in the `AppDelegate` but I get in the time of view did appear only but i need the value inside the `viewDidLoad`. Below is my code

```
//in AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureBlock = ^(NSError *error) {

        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No Albums Available"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];

    };

    //    ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock listGroupBlock

    void (^assetGroupEnumerator)( ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *)= ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {

        NSLog(@"Block123");

        if (group == nil)

        {

            return;

        }

        if ([[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] isEqualToString:@"FlipDemo"]) {

            [self.groups addObject:group];

            NSLog(@" arr 123 %@",self.groups);

            return ;

        }



        if (stop) {

            return;

        }

    };

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        NSLog(@"Block Out");

        [self.assetLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll

                                         usingBlock: assetGroupEnumerator

                                       failureBlock:failureBlock];



    });
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

  appdelegate=(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

  self.groups=appdelegate.groups;

    NSLog(@"// ,%@",self.groups);//Null Value

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    self.groups=appdelegate.groups;

    NSLog(@"// ,%@",self.groups);//Get the url from the asset

     NSLog(@"did appear");

}
```

Comment: If you want it in `viewDidLoad`, why are you doing it asynchronously?

Comment: yes..i want in viewdidload.i put asynchronous in appdelegate.

Comment: Set up a semaphore before dispatching asynchronously, and signal it from the last line of the asynchronous block. Wait for the semaphore in your `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: You don't want to dispatch it to a background queue because `enumerateGroupsWithTypes` is already asynchronous.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yikes! No, never block the main thread.

Comment: @Rob I agree that one shouldn't block the main thread. But then the design needs to change to not need that data in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @Newbee By the way, I believe you misunderstand the point of the `stop` variable. It's not something you check to see if it has stopped. It's something you set when _you_ want to stop the enumeration yourself. Remove that `if (stop)...` code from your block.

Answer (score 2):

You are updating your `groups` asynchronously. Thus, you should not expect it to be available by `viewDidLoad` (nor `viewDidAppear`, for that matter).

You should employ an asynchronous pattern. Either:

1. For example, have `viewDidLoad` add an observer of the `groups` property (but don't update that property until all of the groups are retrieved).
2. Or, alternatively, have the completion block post a notification when the updating of `groups` is done, and have `viewDidLoad` add itself as an observer of that notification.
3. Or have `viewDidLoad` initiate the enumeration itself, and then it will know when the enumeration is done. Specifically, when the `group` parameter of the enumeration method is `nil`, you know it's done. And if you do this in `viewDidLoad`, you can then trigger whatever UI update you want at that point (e.g. reload table or collection view, etc.).

Personally, I'd lean towards the third option, as it is probably the cleanest (and avoids some timing related annoyances with the other approaches).

Either way, don't expect asynchronous method to be done by any given point in the app launching process. And don't try to make it behave synchronously, either. Employ asynchronous pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It's just coincidence that the data becomes available between viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear. You're doing an asynchronous call from which you don't know when it calls the assetGroupEnumerator block. So there might also be cases where the data isn't even available in viewDidAppear.
So you should rethink your architecture. One way would be to fetch the data in viewDidLoad asynchronously and while waiting for the data show some message or loading indication to the user. When the data finished loading, present it.